# Extracting a rectangular pixel region from an image

Tags: java, image, extract, pixel, region

I need to extract a pixel region described by (2n+1) x (2m+1) centred on leftimage (xl,yl). n and m are user input parameters and xl and yl are already defined. Thus far I have this code:

```
for(int xl = n; xl < picOneGreyScale.getWidth() - n; xl++) {
    for(int yl = m; yl < picOneGreyScale.getHeight() - m; yl++) {
        //extract (2n+1) x (2m+1) pixel region centred on leftimage (xl,yl);
        for(int nArea = xl-n; nArea < xl+n+1; nArea++) {
            for(int mArea = yl-m; mArea < yl+m+1; mArea++) {
                *code here*   
            }
}
```

I'm uncertain as to how to continue. I have defined a BufferedImage called leftRegion:

```
BufferedImage leftRegion = new BufferedImage((2*n+1),(2*m+1),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
```

which I intend to use to "extract" my pixel region into. My thoughts thus far are, for where it says *code here* to extract the pixel at the current location (using getRGB?) and then nesting another for loop to place this pixel within the correct x, y coordinates for leftRegion. I'm not sure how to do this however or if I'm thinking too complex. Alternatively it may be possible to use getRGB with extended arguments:

```
getRGB(int startX, int startY, int w, int h, int[] rgbArray, int offset, int scansize)
```

instead of the two inner for loops but again I'm not so hot on how to implement this. Finally there is a method for BufferedImage called copyData which looks like it might be relevant but I'm not sure how to use it. What's the best way to implement this? Many thanks as always.

Additional Information:

Okay so I'm trying to use the getSubImage method of the BufferedImage class:

```
leftRegion = picOneGreyScale.getSubimage(xl, yl, (2*n+1), (2*m+1));
```

only I'm getting an error "(y + height) is outside of Raster". How does getSubImage work exactly? Will the image be centered around xl, yl with the width and height being extended equally either side, or does it work differently? Am I even following the right path?

Comment: I'm also looking into a class called CropImageFilter, I don't know if this will do what I need. If someone could point me in the right direction as to how to do this you'll have all my love. And bacon. *exclaimer: bacon may not be provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I simply replaced the two inner for loops with this:

```
leftRegion = picOneGreyScale.getSubimage(xl-n, yl-n, (2*n+1), (2*m+1));
```